# (phpmailer) Is is fine to use a "from" address that has a different domain name than the website I use to send the mail?

Tags: phpmailer

so I was wondering if setting the sender address as "some_name@not-my-domain.Com" when I send an email through phpmailer (mail()) is fine or if it can cause it to be seen as junk mail? 
no malicious use intended but I use that script as an unofficial tool at work so I would rather make it look like I send the email from my work address.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ok so the "related" side bar helped me more than google and it seems it isn't fine which makes sense.